# Bloomberg stops VBA Application.Ontime

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, bloomberg

I have the following VBA subroutine which is calls itself every second:

```
Public Sub AllTheTime()
    iTimerSet = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Call runMyFunction
    Application.OnTime iTimerSet, "AllTheTime"
End Sub
```

This script is running perfectly: It is recalling itself every second and calculating some stuff.

But when I install the Bloomberg Office Add-On (Bloomberg Ribbon) it is no longer working: It is running exactly one time then it is stopped.  I checked this with Debug.Print. It seems that Bloomberg is stopping the "Application.OnTime" method.

Do you have any ideas what causes this behaviour?

Comment: could it be possible that the addon is using the same variable name?

Comment: @Mech That was not the problem. I renamed all the varibles and function names in a very strange way. But the problem still exists.

Comment: The Bloomberg Office add-on is not always a good bedfellow to other operations in Excel. What is runMyFunction actually doing? If runMyFunction crashes out for some reason, then you won't get to the OnTime() call. Suggest you put a breakpoint in runMyFunction and see if it is getting to the end. Also, I am not sure what happens if runMyFunction takes more than 1 second (in which case your timer is set for the past)?

Comment: Runmyfunction Loops through 10000 cells. Without BB AddOn it worked perfectly. It never took more than 1 second. 
Just in case if it took more than 1 second. What can I do in this case?

Comment: @Ben just put `iTimerSet = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")` ***after*** you call `runMyFunction`.

Comment: This is still not working. @assylias: I put it after runMyFunction. Nevertheless the code runs exactly ONE time. 'Application.OnTime iTimerSet, "AllTheTime"' is not working with an active Bloomberg AddOn. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ben I am not sure - I generally avoid using this approach (interacting with bloomberg formulae from VBA) as it's quite fragile. It's more robust to use the COM v3 VBA API.

Comment: I am not using a single Bloomberg formula right now. I am running my script without any use of Bloomberg functionalities. As soon as I install the Bloomberg AddOn my script is not working. But I did not change anything.

Comment: Bloomberg published an update to their Excel API on September 21, 2020.  It also broke the `Application.OnTime` call in every instance I have reviewed.

Comment: Perhaps Bloomberg add-in is overwriting the OnTime function?